# .text() not returning value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to create a `<ul><li>` of the classes attached to the div `.lista-produtos`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

var alts = {};
$('.lista-produtos').each(function(){
  var classes2 = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < classes2.length; i++) {
      var matches2 = /^tipo\-(.+)/.exec(classes2[i]);
      if (matches2 != null) {
        var produto = matches2[1];
      }
    }
  if(!alts[classes2]){
      alts[classes2] = true;
      $('ul.filters').append('<li class="filter-produto">'+ produto +'</li>');    
  }  
});
});
```

The code above generates `<li>`s inside of the `<ul class="filters">`. So the code is something like this:

```
<ul class="filters">
<li class="filter-produto active">Produto 1<li>
<li class="filter-produto">Produto 2<li>
<li class="filter-produto">Produto 3<li>
<li class="filter-produto">Produto 4<li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, one of the `<li>`s will have an additional class named "active", and the problem is I need to get the text inside of it (Produto 1) to use on another code but it's not working:

```
var produto2 = $('li.filter-produto.active').text();
```

I tested `alert(produto2);` to see if the code worked but it only returns a blank value and not the text inside the `<li>`.

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that puts an `active` class on any of the `li` elements, which would be why you don't find it later.

Comment: i have copy/paste your code in a jsfiddle, and all works perfectly.

Comment: It's also not clear where `tipo-` should come from :-?

Comment: No no no, Newly created element could not do like that. It should be like:   $('parentElement').find('li.filter-produto.active').text(). You have to point that li element like that. 'parentElement' must not be newly created element.

Comment: It was a dumb mistake. Sorry guys. The guy on the comment below helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly I don't have rep to comment, but can you show us the order of the stuff happening?

Perhaps you are asking for the value before the active class it attached to the li. Something like this:

```
// Function to create the ul and lis

var produto2 = $('li.filter-produto.active').text();

// Function that adds the active class
```

So maybe the li.filter-produto.active doesn't exist when you ask for it's value?

Comment: Yes. That was exactly the problem. I feel retarded right now, lol. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's Wednesday, you'll get over the hump ; P